# python: no reconoce un folder que a sido creado dentro del directorio

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-import

tengo la siguiente distribución en mis carpetas

```
lambdas:
 - functions
    - __init__.py
    - handlers
      - set_ranges_contracts.py
      - __init__.py
    - packages
      - utils
      - dao
      - __init__.py
```

y desde set_ranges_contracts.py estoy importando

```
from packages.utils.helper import generate_name, add_extension
```

me da el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_ranges_contracts.py", line 11, in <module>
    from packages.utils.helper import generate_name, add_extension
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packages'
```

A pesar de tener los **init**.py me está dando el error. Alguna recomendación ?

Comment: Tendrías que salir del directorio en que te encuentras pues la carpeta exta un nivel arriba se donde estas, recomiendo que hagas los `import` con el módulo `os`

Comment: @Christian esto servirá para cuando lo despliegue en una lambda ?

Comment: No sé a qué te refieres con `lambda` pero es tontería sirve psrsmtodo, es buena formamde prevenir posibles fallos

Comment: Vamos a ver. Los paquetes se importan desde los directorios del `sys.path` o desde el mismo directorio donde está el fichero python. `packages` no está en el mismo directorio. ¿Has hecho algo para que esté en la ruta de búsqueda? Te aconsejo que mires la documentación sobre [paquetes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema, llegué a solucionar, agregando la ruta o path del sistema a la carpeta o script que estás trabajando.

En el archivo que estas trabajando agrega los siguiente:

`import os, sys`         `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))`